# VB WPF xaml file referencing My.Resources

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm having trouble getting the xaml portion of the VB version of a working C# WPF project to work.

In the top section of the VB project xaml file:

```
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:My.Resources"
```

The first error message for the xaml file is:

```
"Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'My.Resources' that could not be found."
```

A typical reference to 'resources' within the xaml file:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="32" Text="{x:Static resources:Resources.Foo_ProjectName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlock}" />
```

The VB project has no "root namespace". If I add a root namespace 'Foo' and change the above directive to
the following, it makes no difference - same message about the undefined CLR namespace:

```
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Foo.My.Resources"
```

Overview of the Resources.Designer.vb file (auto-generated so I have no control over it):

```
Namespace My.Resources
    ...
    Public Module Resources
        ...
        Public ReadOnly Property Foo_ProjectName() As String
            Get
                Return ResourceManager.GetString("Foo_ProjectName", resourceCulture)
            End Get
        End Property
        ...
    End Module
End Namespace
```

The working C# version of this project:

xaml file:

```
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Foo.Properties"
```

Partial code from the Resources.Designer.cs file

```
namespace Foo.Properties {
    public class Resources {
        ...

        public static string Foo_ProjectName {
            get {
                return ResourceManager.GetString("Foo_ProjectName", resourceCulture);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried poking at this, and I can't reproduce the error you see.    I used `xmlns:res="clr-namespace:My.Resources` and `xmlns:res="clr-namespace:My` with no issues in the namespace declaration.  I did not, however, have any success then referring to a resource there.  I ran into an error "member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name."  There is a default root namespace for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think resources in `My.Resources` are compatible with reference from WPF xaml based on some testing.  It seems like the problem is that the code generator used for it puts the strongly-typed references to the resources into a `Module` (equivalent to a `static class` in C#) rather than a `Class` (equivalent to a `class` in C#), and the xaml compiler only supports the latter.  This seems to be a function of the use of a special "VbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator" for `My.Resources` compared with a "ResXFileCodeGenerator" for any other .resx file.  I suspect this is a difference in behavior for the default resources in a C# project compared with the `My.Resources` in a VB project.

The workaround to this is to not use `My.Resources` for the purpose.  Instead, use a custom .resx file in the project.  You will then be able to refer to the resources from xaml as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks - I was leaning this way over the last couple of days, but your answer has convinced me that this is the case.